# Twitter filtered stream operational disconnects

Tags: javascript, discord, twitter-streaming-api

I've created a discord bot that runs on a raspberry pi 4, which shares tweets from specific users. The stream part of the code is inspired by this one:

https://github.com/bradtraversy/real-time-tweet-stream

I’m listening to a filtered stream and get operational disconnects every now and then. The exact error message is:

```sh
{
errors: [
{
title: ‘operational-disconnect’,
disconnect_type: ‘UpstreamOperationalDisconnect’,
detail: ‘This stream has been disconnected upstream for operational reasons.’,
type: ‘link removed for forum rules’
}
]
}
```

Everytime I get this error, my bot is offline from the stream (but still online on discord) and I have to restart the bot manually in order to reconnect to the stream. Is there a way to prevent this kind of error, and if not, to automatically restart the stream when it get errors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the error. It's not in the code. I'm using screen in order to open many terminal windows when I'm connected via ssh from another computer.

I wanted to be able to close the terminal (and the ssh connection) without ending the js script. I've google it and found screen but it seems to have some problems.

When I stay connected with my other computer and don't close ssh, it's not getting operational disconnects.

So now the question is why it's getting those operational disconnects when I put the terminal running the script in background using screen?

Comment: The same thing is happening to me, try to add a screen-related tag to your question.